# Build PyQt project on Window7

Tags: windows, powershell, pyqt, pyqt4, cx-freeze

Recently, I've written a project that require connect to Google Map APIs. I built it successfully on Ubuntu 16.04 with cx_freeze, but when built on Window 7, it showed the error like the figure.

```
> Missing modules:
? Cookie imported from requests.compat
? HTMLParser imported from reportlab.platypus.paraparser
? Image imported from reportlab.lib.utils
? OpenSSL imported from requests.help
? OpenSSL.SSL imported from requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl, urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
? OpenSSL.crypto imported from requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl, urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
? PyQt5.QtCore imported from PIL.ImageQt
? PyQt5.QtGui imported from PIL.ImageQt
? PySide.QtCore imported from PIL.ImageQt
? PySide.QtGui imported from PIL.ImageQt
? StringIO imported from reportlab.lib.utils, requests.compat, requests.packages.urllib3.packages.six, urllib3.packages.
? __builtin__ imported from PIL.Image, reportlab, reportlab.lib.utils
? __main__ imported from bdb, pdb
? _abcoll imported from requests.packages.urllib3.packages.ordered_dict, urllib3.packages.ordered_dict
? _dummy_threading imported from dummy_threading
? _frozen_importlib imported from importlib, importlib.abc
? _frozen_importlib_external imported from importlib, importlib._bootstrap, importlib.abc
? _posixsubprocess imported from subprocess
? _scproxy imported from urllib.request
? _winreg imported from platform, requests.utils
? backports.ssl_match_hostname imported from requests.packages.urllib3.packages.ssl_match_hostname, urllib3.packages.ssl_match_hostname
? cPickle imported from reportlab.lib.utils
? cffi imported from PIL.Image, PIL.PyAccess
? cookielib imported from requests.compat
? cryptography imported from requests.help, requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl, urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
? cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl imported from requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl, urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
? cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.x509 imported from requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl, urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
? cryptography.x509.extensions imported from requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl, urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
? dummy_thread imported from requests.packages.urllib3.packages.ordered_dict, urllib3.packages.ordered_dict
? future_builtins imported from reportlab
? grp imported from pathlib, shutil, tarfile
? htmlentitydefs imported from reportlab.platypus.paraparser
? jarray imported from reportlab.lib.utils
? java.awt.image imported from reportlab.lib.utils
? java.lang imported from platform, xml.sax._exceptions
? javax.imageio imported from reportlab.lib.utils
? macfs imported from reportlab.lib.utils
? macostools imported from reportlab.lib.utils
? md5 imported from reportlab.lib.utils
? netbios imported from uuid
? org.python.core imported from copy, pickle, xml.sax
? os.path imported from constant, os, pkgutil, py_compile, reportlab.lib.utils, requests.adapters, tracemalloc, unittest, unittest.util, utils
? places imported from utils
? posix imported from os
? pwd imported from getpass, http.server, netrc, pathlib, posixpath, shutil, tarfile, webbrowser
? pyfribidi2 imported from reportlab.pdfgen.textobject
? reportlab.lib.pyHnj imported from reportlab.lib.utils
? reportlab.local_rl_mods imported from reportlab
? reportlab_mods imported from reportlab
? requests.packages.urllib3.packages.six.moves imported from requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool, requests.packages.urllib3.response, requests.packages.urllib3.util.response
? requests.packages.urllib3.packages.six.moves.http_client imported from requests.packages.urllib3.connection, requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions
? requests.packages.urllib3.packages.six.moves.urllib.parse imported from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager, requests.packages.urllib3.request
? rl_config imported from reportlab.lib.utils
? rlextra.pageCatcher.pageCatcher imported from reportlab.lib.pdfencrypt
? sets imported from reportlab.platypus.doctemplate
? simplejson imported from requests.compat
? socks imported from urllib3.contrib.socks
? termios imported from getpass, tty
? tests.test_platypus_tables imported from reportlab.platypus.tables
? thread imported from requests.packages.urllib3.packages.ordered_dict,    urllib3.packages.ordered_dict
? urllib.getproxies imported from requests.compat
? urllib.getproxies_environment imported from requests.compat
? urllib.proxy_bypass imported from requests.compat
? urllib.proxy_bypass_environment imported from requests.compat
? urllib.quote imported from requests.compat
? urllib.quote_plus imported from requests.compat
? urllib.unquote imported from requests.compat
? urllib.unquote_plus imported from requests.compat
? urllib.urlencode imported from googlemaps.client, requests.compat
? urllib2 imported from reportlab.lib.utils, requests.compat
? urllib3.packages.six.moves imported from urllib3.connectionpool, urllib3.response, urllib3.util.response
? urllib3.packages.six.moves.http_client imported from urllib3.connection, urllib3.exceptions
? urllib3.packages.six.moves.urllib.parse imported from urllib3.poolmanager, urllib3.request
? urlparse imported from requests.compat
? vms_lib imported from platform
? win32wnet imported from uuid
This is not necessarily a problem - the modules may not be needed on this platform.
```

Beside that, it looks like the output file is not an .exe file. So how do I fix these problems. Thank in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using PyInstaller? I export my apps easily with it in Windows 7. It's a whole lot simpler.

Comment: Yeah. I have tried it and it worked like a charm. :)